# Going to random Url's through iMacros

Tags: url, redirect, random, imacros

Hey guys please help me out on this one. How can I get my iMacros on mozilla to go to random URL's  For instance first on google.com second on gmail.com third on youtube and so on

I don't want anything like this :-

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=www.google.com/
URL GOTO=www.youtube.com
Refresh
```

Instead it should surf something like this:-

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=www.google.com/  OR  www.youtube.com  OR  www.yahoo.com 
Refresh
```

and that too randomly

Comment: IceD thanks but can you fully convert that script for me to Imacros format Sincerely thanks for ur support

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is if clauses.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX"+"\n";
macro +="TAB T=1"+"\n";
macro +="TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS"+"\n";
macro +="URL GOTO={{link}}"+"\n";


var link=["www.google.com","www.youtube.com","www.yahoo.com"];

var random=getRandomInt(1,3);

random--;

iimSet("link",link[random])
iimPlay(macro)
```

You will find random function on the link bellow. Also there are tons of examples of iMacros and JS on stackoverflow.

[Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range/1527820#1527820)

Comment: IceD thanks but can you fully convert that script for me to Imacros format Sincerely thanks for ur support

Comment: But when I paste this as a script in iMacros it shows error in 2 nd line var

Comment: The extension has to be .js and only .js nothing else. No .iim no .iim.js or any other variation.